# Reading a user input (character or string of letters) into ggplot command inside a switch statement or a nested ifelse (with functions in it)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have code like

```
AA <- as.integer(readline("Select any number"))

switch(AA, 
1={
      num <-as.integer(readline("Select any one of the options \n"))
      print('You have selected option 1')
      #reading user data
      var <- readline("enter the variable name \n")
      #aggregating the data based on required condition
      gg1 <- aggregate(cbind(get(var))~Mi+hours,a, FUN=mean)
      #Ploting
     ggplot(gg1, aes(x = hours, y = get(var), group = Mi, fill = Mi, color = Mi)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(stat="smooth", alpha = I(0.01))


},
2={
  print('bar')    
},
{
   print('default')
}
)
```

The dataset is [dataset][1]

I have loaded the dataset into object list

```
a <- read.table(file.choose(), header=FALSE,col.names= c("Ei","Mi","hours","Nphy","Cphy","CHLphy","Nhet","Chet","Ndet","Cdet","DON","DOC","DIN","DIC","AT","dCCHO","TEPC","Ncocco","Ccocco","CHLcocco","PICcocco","par","Temp","Sal","co2atm","u10","dicfl","co2ppm","co2mol","pH"))
```

I am getting error like

```
source ("switch_statement_check.R")
Select any one of the options 
1
[1] "You have selected option 1"
enter the variable name 
Nphy
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
>
```

gg1 is getting data that is fine.
I dont know what to do to make the variable entered by user to work in that ggplot command.
Please suggest any solution for this.

The dput output

```
structure(list(Ei = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Mi = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), hours = 1:6, Nphy = c(0.1023488, 0.104524, 0.1064772, 
0.1081702, 0.1095905, 0.110759), Cphy = c(0.6534707, 0.6448216, 
0.6369597, 0.6299084, 0.6239005, 0.6191941), CHLphy = c(0.1053458, 
0.110325, 0.1148174, 0.1187672, 0.122146, 0.1249877), Nhet = c(0.04994161, 
0.04988347, 0.04982555, 0.04976784, 0.04971029, 0.04965285), 
    Chet = c(0.3308593, 0.3304699, 0.3300819, 0.3296952, 0.3293089, 
    0.3289243), Ndet = c(0.04991916, 0.04984045, 0.04976363, 
    0.0496884, 0.04961446, 0.04954156), Cdet = c(0.3307085, 0.3301691, 
    0.3296314, 0.3290949, 0.3285598, 0.3280252), DON = c(0.05042275, 
    0.05085697, 0.05130091, 0.05175249, 0.05220978, 0.05267118
    ), DOC = c(49.76304, 49.52745, 49.29323, 49.06034, 48.82878, 
    48.59851), DIN = c(14.9933, 14.98729, 14.98221, 14.9781, 
    14.97485, 14.97225), DIC = c(2050.132, 2050.264, 2050.396, 
    2050.524, 2050.641, 2050.758), AT = c(2150.007, 2150.007, 
    2150.007, 2150.007, 2150.007, 2150.007), dCCHO = c(0.964222, 
    0.930869, 0.8997098, 0.870544, 0.843196, 0.8175117), TEPC = c(0.1339044, 
    0.1652179, 0.1941872, 0.2210289, 0.2459341, 0.2690721), Ncocco = c(0.1040715, 
    0.1076058, 0.1104229, 0.1125141, 0.1140222, 0.1151228), Ccocco = c(0.6500288, 
    0.6386706, 0.6291149, 0.6213265, 0.6152447, 0.6108502), CHLcocco = c(0.1087667, 
    0.1164099, 0.1225822, 0.1273103, 0.1308843, 0.1336465), PICcocco = c(0.1000664, 
    0.1001396, 0.1007908, 0.101836, 0.1034179, 0.1055634), par = c(0, 
    0, 0.8695131, 1.551317, 2.777707, 4.814341), Temp = c(9.9, 
    9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9), Sal = c(31.31, 31.31, 31.31, 31.31, 
    31.31, 31.31), co2atm = c(370, 370, 370, 370, 370, 370), 
    u10 = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01), dicfl = c(-2.963256, 
    -2.971632, -2.980446, -2.989259, -2.997877, -3.005702), co2ppm = c(565.1855, 
    565.7373, 566.3179, 566.8983, 567.466, 567.9814), co2mol = c(0.02562326, 
    0.02564828, 0.0256746, 0.02570091, 0.02572665, 0.02575002
    ), pH = c(7.879427, 7.879042, 7.878636, 7.878231, 7.877835, 
    7.877475)), .Names = c("Ei", "Mi", "hours", "Nphy", "Cphy", 
"CHLphy", "Nhet", "Chet", "Ndet", "Cdet", "DON", "DOC", "DIN", 
"DIC", "AT", "dCCHO", "TEPC", "Ncocco", "Ccocco", "CHLcocco", 
"PICcocco", "par", "Temp", "Sal", "co2atm", "u10", "dicfl", "co2ppm", 
"co2mol", "pH"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

As per the below suggestions I have tried a lot but it is not working.

Summarizing I will say:

var <- readline("enter a variable name") 
I cant use get(var) inside any command but not inside ggplot, it wont work.

gg1$var it also doesnt work, even after changing the column names. Does it have a solution or should I just choose to import from an excel sheet, thats better?

Tried with if else and functions

```
  fun1 <- function() {
  print('You have selected option 1')
  my <- as.character((readline("enter the variable name \n")))
  gg1 <- aggregate(cbind(get(my))~Mi+hours,a, FUN=mean)
  names(gg1)[3] <- my
  #print(names(gg1))
  ggplot (gg1,aes_string(x="hours",y=(my),group="Mi",color="Mi")) + geom_point()
}



my <- as.integer(readline("enter a number"))

ifelse(my == 1,fun1(),"")
ifelse(my == 2,print ("its 2"),"")
ifelse(my == 3,print ("its 3"),"")

ifelse(my != (1 || 2|| 3) ,print("wrong number"),"")
```

Not working either...:(

Comment: can you please make your question self-contained, ie, not just have a link to your data and make sure that we can just copy and paste your code into our consoles.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see how your data looks in R after you've loaded it. Are you storing it as a data.frame? If so, show us `dput(head(yourData))`. In that case, you should also use the `data` argument of `aggregate`.

Comment: @rawr I have added steps for how i am importing data..please check

Comment: @shujaa dput output I have pasted...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Nah, it's data.frame (look at the `dput`). The only thing the `cbind` seems to do is make the name of `gg1`'s third column `V1` instead of `get(var)` (just like that, unevaluated).

Comment: And using `switch` should be no different than `if` and `else`, just less typing.

Comment: Also, in your `if` try, you completely ignored my recommendation about `aes_string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a naming problem. Running your code one line at a time, you can see what `gg1` looks like:

```
> gg1 <- aggregate(cbind(get(var))~Mi+hours,a, FUN=mean)
> head(gg1)
  Mi hours        V1
1  1     1 0.1021998
2  2     1 0.1021966
3  3     1 0.1022071
4  4     1 0.1022026
5  5     1 0.1022019
6  6     1 0.1022035
```

Notice the column is named `V1`, not `Nphy`. Correcting `y = V1` in the `ggplot` seems to work just fine.

If you want the column name preserved, just rename it after the aggregate.

```
gg1 <- aggregate(cbind(get(var))~Mi+hours,a, FUN=mean)
names(gg1)[3] <- var
```

Rather than using `aes()` with `get(var)`, I'd also recommend using `aes_string()` in this case, i.e., `aes_string(x = "hours", y = var, group = "Mi", fill= "Mi", color = "Mi"))`.

### Edits:

In addition to `aes_string` in your ggplot, you need to `eval(var)` in your aggregate formula if you want this in a function. This works fine for me:

```
makePlot <- function(var = readline("Enter the variable name\n")) {
    gg1 <- aggregate(cbind(get(eval(var))) ~ Mi + hours, a, FUN=mean)
    names(gg1)[3] <- var
    print(ggplot(gg1, aes_string(x = "hours", y = var, group = "Mi",
                          fill= "Mi", color = "Mi")) +
        geom_point())
}

# works with an argument:
makePlot(var = "Nphy") 
# works interactively:
makePlot() # enter Nphy at console when prompted
```

Notice both the `aes_string` in the `ggplot` and the `get(eval(var))` in the `aggregate`. This assumes your data.frame is named `a` and exists in the global environment.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that get command changes the column name of variable and puts a default value V1, I am unable to manage having the original column name after the aggregation. Any Idea on how to keep the column name intact? there is one suggestion of keeping its original class using as, let me check.

Comment: Yup, Renaming works fine. I was looking through class change or coerce or some other method but it doesn't make a difference so I will implement using your suggestion. Thanks for the help..:)

Comment: Sorry, It works fine if I execute the commands individually, but again the same error if I do the source("file name")..."object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"...this error is repeating.

Comment: @statisticalbeginner Well, then something's different. Are you sure you saved the new version in the file you're sourcing? Is your data loaded in that file, or in the global environment? What you should do is clear your workspace, put a `stop()` line in your file right before wherever the error occurs (is it the plotting or the aggregate?), and then try to run the next line of code. Look at all your objects, make sure they seem right, and look for what's different.

Comment: You could do something similar by wrapping it in a function and using `browser()`, but it's just standard debugging. Something isn't named like you think it is,  or isn't in the place you think it is. Try to isolate the problem.

Comment: I have tried with functions and if else loops again, and no help the same error I am getting. I can able to use get(var) and run the commands individually and get the required result. But If I run then through source I will be getting the error. Is there something problem with calling a user input variable into ggplot inside a switch statement or function?

Comment: Thnaks. Finally it worked with both switch and ifelse. I was trying all sorts of things, still soo much to learn....anyway Thanks again..:)

Comment: One last question. I can use aes_string and perform inside ggplot. How can we manage the same inside a plot function Ex: plot(x = gg1$hours, y = var1, type="l", col="red", xlab="", ylab="").....This doesnt work inside a plot function. Any idea?

Comment: Just use `[` instead of `$` for subsetting/accessing columns. `plot(x = gg1[, "hours"], y = gg1[, var1], ...)`.